# Eyecon datepicker doesn't work in combination with bootstrap and reduced page size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am prototyping the UI with bootstrap. I use the [eyecon.ro](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) datepicker.

Basically, it works almost fine. However, there is one problem. The datepicker stops working when I reduce the page size to fit the tablet or mobile format. When I enlarge the page - the control starts to work as it should. Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
            <!------------------------------------------------------------------------ Date Time Picker -->
            <div class="timentry-list-header">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <span id="workDayPicker" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        Today
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="btn btn-default disabled">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                var nowTemp = new Date();
                var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#workDayPicker').datepicker({
                        autoclose: true,
                        endDate: new Date(),
                        todayBtn: true,
                        todayHighlight: true
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <!-----------------------------------------------------------------------END Date Time Picker -->
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reduce the page size". The whole concept of Bootstrap is to have a responsive page by using proper class attributes. Perhaps provide a screenshot of what is happening. What happens when you change to col-md-8 or other variations? Please provide more info.

Comment: "Reduce size" - I mean when I click the edge of the page and drag it aside. What happens: the control still appear on the page, but when I click it the calendar doesn't pop up. Nothing happens. When I enlarge the page - the control works fine!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is not included in jQuery mobile by default.  Do you have it?

This may also be a duplicate of [JQuery mobile datepicker doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277839/jquery-mobile-datepicker-doesnt-work)

Comment: Well, my date picker works when the page size is more than 992px or so. It doesn't work when I reduce the page size! I use jquery-1.9.1.min.js and bootstrap.min.js on my page. So I do not have jQuery mobile. And Is I perceive this is not  jQuery mobile plugin!?